# Ingesting data from Snowflake to Azure Data Catalog

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-catalog

I have a project to ingest metadata from the Snowflake data warehouse into the Azure Data Catalog (ADC). The ADC does not natively support this, so I must use the ADC API or ODBC.

Before I proceed on implementing the API solution, I thought it wise to ask if anyone has suggestions on this.  A Google search returned nothing of note.

Comment: tried it once, and got it to work with the Desktop client and a custom ODBC driver. To be honest it was not worth the time 12 months ago. Maybe things have changed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately ODBC will not work either.  I am moving onto a solution to load via API.

Answer (score -1):

The API or ODBC are the best choices.

Comment: ODBC is not supported for Snowflake.  Per Q&A site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/49756/data-catalog-and-snowflake-db.html